# How check the ConnectionState of Firestore snapshot stream with StreamProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

This example from the cloud_firestore documentation uses a `StreamBuilder` and the `ConnectionState` of an `AsyncSnapshot` to handle the stream in its different states. Is there a similar way to manage the `ConnectionState` when accessing the stream via a `StreamProvider` instead of a `StreamBuilder`? What is the best way of avoiding it to return `null` in the short while until it actually has documents from Firestore?

Here the example from the cloud_firestore docs with the StreamBuilder:

```
    class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
              default:
                return new ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Text(document['title']),
                      subtitle: new Text(document['author']),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

I have a rather basic stream:

```
    List<AuditMark> _auditMarksFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot qs) {
      return qs.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
        return AuditMark.fromSnapshot(ds);
      }).toList();
    }

    Stream<List<AuditMark>> get auditMarks {
      return Firestore.instance
          .collection('_auditMarks')
          .snapshots()
          .map(_auditMarksFromSnapshot);
    }
```

This is accessed via a `StreamProvider` (have omitted other providers here):

```
    void main() async {
      runApp(MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<List<AuditMark>>(
              create: (_) => DatabaseService().auditMarks, ),
        ],
        child: MyApp(),
      ));
    }
```

I have tried somehow converting the `QuerySnapshot` to an `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>` but probably got that wrong.
Could of course give the `StreamProvider` some `initialData` like so - but this is cumbersome, error prone and probably expensive:

```
    initialData: <AuditMark>[
      AuditMark.fromSnapshot(await Firestore.instance
          .collection('_auditMarks')
          .orderBy('value')
          .getDocuments()
          .then((value) => value.documents.first))
```

...but I am hoping there is a smarter way of managing the connection state and avoiding it to return null before it can emit documents?

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with this and didn't want to declare an `initialData` to bypass this issue.

What I did was **creating a StreamBuilder as the *child* of StreamProvider**. 
So that I could use the `snapshot.connectionState` property of StreamBuilder **in the** StreamProvider.

Here's the code:

```
    return StreamProvider<List<AuditMark>>.value(
        value: DatabaseService().auditMarks,
        child: StreamBuilder<List<AuditMark>>(
                stream: DatabaseService().auditMarks,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasError) {
                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                            case ConnectionState.none: // if no connection
                                return new Text(
                                    "Offline!",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.red),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                );
                            case ConnectionState.waiting
                                // while waiting the data, this is where you'll avoid NULL
                                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                            default:
                                return ListView.builder(
                                    // in my case I was getting NULL for itemCount
                                    itemCount: logs.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return LogsTile(log: logs[index]);
                                    },
                                );
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return new Text(
                            "Error: ${snapshot.error}",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.red),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        );
                    }
                }
        )
    );
```

Comment: Nice workaround. In my case I would have had to use several nested StreamBuilders because I depend on several StreamProviders, hence preferred the below approach.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but I ended up using a simple bool variable which is true while not all StreamProviders have emitted values.

```
bool _waitForStreams = false;
if (Provider.of<List<AuditMark>>(context) == null) _waitForStreams = true;
if (Provider.of<...>>(context) == null) _waitForStreams = true; 
(etc. repeat for every StreamProvider)

// show "loading..." message while not all StreamProviders have supplied values
if (_waitForStreams) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
              SizedBox(height: 25.0),
              Text('loading...'),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's correct but this is how I implement it.

Since `streamProviser` does not provide a connection state, I first use `streamBuilder` and then `provider.value` to distribute the data:

```
return StreamBuilder<BusinessM>(
    stream: db.businessDetails(), //firebase stream mapped to business model class
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active)
        return Provider<BusinessM>.value(
          value: snapshot.data,
          child: Businesspage(),
        );
      else
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who want to use `StreamProvider` but end up with no `ConnectionState` state to use. For some of the cases, *null* represent the state of *"waiting for the first data"*, not *"no data"*.

In `StreamProvider`, there is no build-in method to detect the state. But we can still warp the state outside of the data:

```
StreamProvider<AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot?>>.value(
  initialData: const AsyncSnapshot.waiting(),
  value: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('books')
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) {
    return AsyncSnapshot.withData(ConnectionState.active, snapshot);
  }),
  child: ...,
);
```

or for firebaseAuth:

```
StreamProvider<AsyncSnapshot<User?>>.value(
  initialData: const AsyncSnapshot.waiting(),
  value: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().map(
    (user) => AsyncSnapshot.withData(ConnectionState.active, user),
  ),
),
```